# Kivy - Video doesn't load

Tags: kivy

I've got this simply code and it doesn't work, in fact the video doesn't load...

Kivy:

```
<Game>:
    orientation: vertical
    Video:
        source: 'chargement.mp4'
        state: 'play'
```

Can you help me ? If you want more code, please asks.

Here the console output : http://textup.fr/117995nO

Comment: Please provide the console output/log from running your app.

Comment: You still haven't provided the console output (for Windows) or logcat (for Android).

Comment: Can you give me the steps to do a 'logcat' or to get 'the console output' ?

Comment: The console output is what appears in your console (Windows cmd.exe) when you run a Kivy app. For logcat, if you're using buildozer you can just run `buildozer android logcat` while your device is connected to the computer. Just keep in mind that logcat is the entire device log, so cut it down to the relevant sections containing Kivy logging.

Comment: Ok so i'm using Kivy Launcher on my android phone... But I added the console output (from cmd.exe) in the topic...

Comment: In fact i'm getting trouble with my android phone when is connected to my PC, so I can just give the console output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put "./" before the video link : "./chargement.mp4"